# How to solve $\arcsin i$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I tried letting $\sin(z) = i$ and then using $\sin(x+iy) = i$ and expanding into $\sin(x)\cos(iy)+\cos(x)\sin(iy) = i$ by the method of comparing coefficients. How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the complex exponential definition of $\sin z$:

$$\sin z = {e^{iz}-e^{-iz}\over 2i} = i$$

Then:

$$e^{iz}-e^{-iz} = -2$$

And solve the resulting quadratic.

Comment: If $z$ is pure imaginary, then there is a possibility that solutions are real.

Answer (score 1):

You can complete your work using the identities :
$$
\cos (ix)=\cosh x \qquad \sin (ix)=i\sinh x
$$

so your equation becomes:
$$
\sin x \cosh y +i \cos x \sinh y=i
$$
equivalent to:
$$
\begin{cases}
\sin x \cosh y=0\\
\cos x\sinh y=1
\end{cases}
$$

since $\cosh y\ne 0 \quad\forall y$, this gives:

$\sin x=0 \rightarrow \cos x=\pm 1 \rightarrow \sinh y=\pm 1$

can you complete from this?

Comment: Yes, thank you: I edit.

Comment: asin(x)=-i*ln(xi+√(1-x²), asin(i)=-iln(ii+√(1-i²))=-iln(-1+√(1+1))=-iln(√(2)-1)=ln(1/(√(2)-1))i=ln(√(2)+1)i≈0.88137358702i

Answer (score 0):

You can also get an answer via the integral definition of the complex arcsine (multi-)function:

$$\arcsin(i)=\int_0^i{dz\over\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$

One path for the countour integral is $z=iy$ with $0\le y\le 1$, which gives

$$\arcsin(i)=\int_0^1{i\,dy\over\sqrt{1+y^2}}=i\int_0^{\pi/4}{\sec^2\theta\over\sec\theta}d\theta=i\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec\theta\,d\theta=\cdots$$